# how to read a data from random place of txt file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am coding a Ranking system for a game written in C++ and want to read a word from random place in a file.

For example, if the 2 last lines of a file are:

```
.  
.  
.  
dani 1902  
pat 1300
```

and I read 1300, how can I get back to read 1902?

Comment: I think http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/ might be the method you are looking for; it will seek the read-position to a specified offset from the top of the file.

Comment: I believe you mean `"Ranking"` system, not a `"Rankin"` system, right? Better yet, read all file values into an `vector` of `struct` and avoid the repeated file access altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When reading information from a file; the process of opening and closing it a bunch of times in succession is not really a good code design. In terms of CPU cycles, cache etc. accessing files from a hard drive is considered slow compare to that which is in ram, or cache. So my advise to you would be the same that David C. Rankin mentioned in the comments above...

> Read all of the files information into a either a large single string buffer, or into a vector of strings where each string in that vector is a single line of text from that file. Then close the file after all of the contents have been read and be done with it.
>
> This makes it a one time find file, open file, and read access file operation.
>
> Afterwards it is a matter of parsing your string or vector of strings which is much faster because these containers are already in ram where the application is running since it is a part of the same process or running thread.